# Facebook microdata debugger not picking up OG and while share debug does

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, microdata, facebook-pixel, facebook-debugger

As per the title, I'm having trouble getting facebook to pick up my microdata information on my website. I've published both as JSON+LD and OpenGraph, but facebook pixel refuses to read it.

I've tried to change multiple times how I format the information, without getting anywhere and checking that the crawler is indeed able to reach the page.

Weirdly the microdata debugger doesn't process my tags
https://business.facebook.com/ads/microdata/debug?url=https%3A%2F%2Foiritaly.it%2Fit%2Fantica-murrina-venezia%2Fbracciale%2Fdonna%2Fbr263a00%2F

[image: microdata debugger screenshot]

While the sharing debugger seems to pick them with no problem
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Foiritaly.it%2Fit%2Fantica-murrina-venezia%2Fbracciale%2Fdonna%2Fbr263a00%2F
[image: sharing debugger screenshot]

Google Rich Result debugger also is able to pick it up with no problem https://search.google.com/test/rich-results
[image: rich result debugger screenshot]

This is the page I've been using as an example, but the problem is present in every product page
https://oiritaly.it/it/antica-murrina-venezia/bracciale/donna/br263a00/

Any idea on what my I been missing?

Right now the pixel feed isn't picking up this information

Thanks